# redirect from login to register form in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm a beginner in react and I have implemented a login and a register form as 2 components using material ui . What I am trying to do is redirect from the login to the register page if I don't have a login account and from register to login if I already have an account . I want to do this using react router but with the official docs I need to have a navbar with my routes but I want to show my login component first and if I click the link then redirect to register and vice-versa .

Link to register in login.js

```
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';

<Link to="/register" variant = "body2">
  Not have an account ? Sign up here 
</Link>
```

Link to login in register.js

```
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';

<Link to="/" variant = "body2">
  Not have an account ? Sign up here 
</Link>
```

App.js has to return login form and I click link to switch

```
function App(){

  return <Login/>

}
```

I tried this below but I got `Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>`

```
import Register from './Components/register';
import Login from './Components/login';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
   <Switch>
     <Route exact path = "/"><Login/></Route>
     <Route path = "/register"><Register/></Route>
   </Switch>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping a <Router> tag around the <Switch> statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly from Login.js you are not using **Link** from `'react-router-dom'`

`import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';`

You are using **Link** from **material ui** and material ui uses **href** to route from **page A** to **page B** not the **to** keyword that is used by `react-router-dom`

**Since you are using forms from Material Ui you can still change the Link and use the react-router-dom Link**

**Your code should be like this:**

**Login.js**

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
//Now with link coming from react-router you can use **to**
<Link to="/register" variant = "body2">
  Not have an account ? Sign up here 
</Link>
```

- So that same logic will apply when you want to route to page on certain events you want to import link the way I showed above

**Now on the app level you have to Wrap it with Router**

```
import Register from './Components/register';
import Login from './Components/login';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
   <Router>
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path = "/"><Login/></Route>
         <Route path = "/register"><Register/></Route>
       </Switch>
   </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the Router wrapper in your app.js you should do the following:

```
import Register from './Components/register';
import Login from './Components/login';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
<Router>
   <Switch>
     <Route exact path = "/"><Login/></Route>
     <Route path = "/register"><Register/></Route>
   </Switch>
</Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```